# Show that $ (p \lor (q \land r)) \land p \iff ( \neg p \lor (q \land r) \implies p) $ is valid.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Show that the following logical expression is universally valid.

$$ (p \lor (q \land r)) \land p \iff ( \neg p \lor (q \land r) \implies p) $$

Here's what I tried so far:

$$[ \ (p \lor (q \land r)) \land p \iff ( \neg p \lor (q \land r) \implies p) \ ]^{\displaystyle \beta } = T$$

Using the definition of $ \iff$, I get

$$ [ \ (p \lor (q \land r)) \land p \ ]^{\displaystyle \beta } = \ [ \ ( \neg p \lor (q \land r) \implies p) \ ]^{\displaystyle \beta } = T $$

Now I would have to distinguish between two cases, namely when $\displaystyle \beta(p) = T$ and when $\displaystyle \beta(p) = F$ and here is my problem. When I start to show the first case, I end up getting $[ \ (p \lor (q \land r)) \land p \ ]^{\displaystyle \beta } = [ \ p \lor (q \land r) \ ]^{\displaystyle \beta }$ but I don't know how I got rid of the $ \ \land p \ $ operation.

Comment: Are you allowed in this to use truth tables?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We have to specifically use the variable assignment method.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the question correctly?  How many $\lnot$ in the original?

Comment: Can you show that both sides of the $\iff$ are equivalent to just $p$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c| c|c|c| c|}
\hline
      p
&
      q
&
      r
&
     q\land r
&
     p \lor (q\land r) 
&
     (p \lor (q\land r))\land p
\\\hline
      T
&
      T
&
      T
&
      T
&
      T
&
      T
\\\hline
      T
&
      T
&
      F
&
      F
&
      T
&
      T
\\\hline
      T
&
      F
&
      T
&
      T
&
      T 
&
      T
\\\hline
      T
&
      F
&
      F
&
     F
&
    T
&
     T
\\\hline
      F
&
      T
&
      T
&
     T
&
     T
&
     F
\\\hline
      F
&
      T
&
      F
&
     F
&
     F 
&
    F
\\\hline
      F
&
      F
&
      T
&
     F
&
     F 
&
    F
\\\hline
      F
&
      F
&
      F
&
     F
&
    F 
&
     F
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c| c|c|c|c| c|}
\hline
      p
&
      q
&
      r
&
     \lnot p
&
     (q\land r) 
&
     ( \neg p \lor (q \land r)) 
&
     ( \neg p \lor (q \land r)) \implies p
\\\hline
      T
&
      T
&
      T
&
     F
&
     T 
&
     T
&
    T
\\\hline
      T
&
      T
&
      F
&
     F
&
     F 
&
    F
&
    T
\\\hline
      T
&
      F
&
      T
&
     F
&
     F 
&
     F
&
     T
\\\hline
      T
&
      F
&
      F
&
     F
&
     F 
&
     F
&
     T
\\\hline
      F
&
      T
&
      T
&
     T
&
     T 
&
     T 
&
     F
\\\hline
      F
&
      T
&
      F
&
     T
&
     F 
&
     T
&
     F
\\\hline
      F
&
      F
&
      T
&
     T
&
     F 
&
     T 
&
     F
\\\hline
      F
&
      F
&
      F
&
     T
&
    F 
&
     T
&
    F
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

If you do not want to use truth table, you can reason by contradiction.

Assume that :

> $(p \lor (q \land r)) \land p \iff ( \neg p \lor (q \land r) \implies p)$

is **not** valid.

This means that, for some variable assignment $\beta$ we have :

> $[(p \lor (q \land r)) \land p]^{\beta} = \text T \text { and } [(\neg p \lor (q \land r) \implies p)]^{\beta} = \text F$.